# Ignore certificate errors when requesting a URL in Java

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to print a URL (without having a browser involved at all) but the URL is currently throwing the following:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I'm calling the URL using a JEditorPane's setPage method, which just takes a URL as a parameter. Assuming I can't change anything server side and I still need to get to this resource, how would I go about ignoring the certificate error (or something else that gets me to my goal)?

Accessing this URL via a browser tells me the site is untrusted and asks me if I want to proceed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Extend `JEditorPane` to override the [`getStream()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#getStream(java.net.URL)) method.

Inside that method, you can [open a `URLConnection`.](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection()) Test whether it is an [`HttpsURLConnection`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html). If it is, [initialize](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html#init(javax.net.ssl.KeyManager[],%20javax.net.ssl.TrustManager[],%20java.security.SecureRandom)) your [own `SSLContext`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLContext.html#getInstance(java.lang.String)) with a custom [`X509TrustManager`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager.html) that doesn't perform any [checks.](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager.html#checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[],%20java.lang.String)) [Get the context's `SSLSocketFactory`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html#getSSLSocketFactory()) and [set it as the socket factory](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html#setSSLSocketFactory(javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory)) for the connection. Then return the `InputStream` [from the connection.](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream())

This will defeat any attempts by the runtime to protect the user from a spoof site serving up malware. If that's *really* what you want…

Answer (score 3):

This is possibly because your certificate  in your keystore  for accessing target `HTTPS` URL does not match the certificate from server.

You need to import the certificate in to your JVM's keystore.
Obtain keystore certificatesto access this URL and then importit into the main keystore with

`keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore /path/to/custom/keystore -destkeystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts`

Assuming you are using Java from `$JAVA_HOME`

Comment: That may indeed be the case. Also see http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/secureinternet2/

Answer (score 2):

I would use erickson solution.
Another way is to add server's certificate (probably self signed) to your trusted certificates KeyStore (I would do it just in your test enviroment).
Use:

```
java InstallCert YourHost
```

to create a **jssecacerts** file
then copy it to the following folder:

```
$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is the same server that you will be contacting each time, it might be okay to simply trust this one certificate by adding it to the trust store. I wouldn't add this to the default cacerts file, but you can make your own keystore and specify it through the javax.net.ssl.trustStore system property.

Lastly, if you want to disable PKIX checking completely (which you should only do if you understand that this will compromise security quite a lot) the only way is to implement your own SSL context and trust manager as erickson has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

On a related note: my mutual certifcate authentication with a WCF .net Web Service was causing issues in my test environment. I added these two lines to my code to fix the problem and allow me to work through the issue:

```
//Uncomment this in case server demands some unsafe operations       
System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true");       

//this command allowed me to see the detailed debugger log for detecting the
//issue with my certs.
System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","all");
```

Here is a nice reference for dealing with SSL negotiation and certifcates in a Java/Windows/Unix world: [Transport Layer Security (TLS) Renegotiation Issue Readme](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/tlsreadme2-176330.html)