# SSL connection for testing purposes

Tags: java, ssl

I'm required to write a SSL connection, but It requires a signed certificate. There is a way to disable the checking so that I can only test my application.
Regards,

Comment: Hi please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2a694281/ignore-certificate-errors-when-requesting-a-url-in-java/2694367#2694367

Comment: @ring bearer- that page yields a not-found error.  Did you mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694281/ignore-certificate-errors-when-requesting-a-url-in-java/2694367#2694367 ?

Comment: Yes! copy paste gone wrong. But a developer should be able to figure that out regardless :)

Answer (score 2):

Just create a self-signed certificate: http://novosial.org/openssl/self-signed/

Comment: it is hard to follow, do you have already some self-signed certificates

Comment: You can google around for different instructions that may be easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve this? This seems like you could use/write a TrustManager that trusts all certificates and thereby enable you to continue on to your app.