# Sending http request to server have exception sometimes happen

Tags: java, ssl, network-programming, httpwebrequest

```
URL oauth = new URL(URL);
URLConnection oauth_connection = oauth.openConnection();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            oauth_connection.getInputStream()));

String inputLine = "";

String line;

//System.out.println(in.readLine());
while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
    inputLine += line;

in.close();
```

Throws exception at the `BufferedReader` line:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>       at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)

Comment: but half of the time, it gave result back successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably either have a self-signed certificate, or a chained certificate where some portion of the chain is not trusted.

You can import the certificate into your trust store see [Digital Certificate: How to import .cer file in to .truststore file using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373295/digital-certificate-how-to-import-cer-file-in-to-truststore-file-using)

Or you can ignore the problem as in this question [Ignore certificate errors when requesting a URL in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694281/ignore-certificate-errors-when-requesting-a-url-in-java)

Comment: but half of the time, it gave result back successfully

Comment: Maybe you are hitting a load balancer that relies on the servers for the cert instead of having its own and one of the servers behind the balancer has a bad or different certificate that you also need to install in your trust store?

Comment: but after shut down one server, it still has that problem, half and half.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to add the server certificate to your trusted Java key store if your client is written in Java.

Refer this page.
https://blogs.oracle.com/gc/entry/unable_to_find_valid_certification

Comment: but half of the time, it gave result back successfully